# Intentar eliminar item asociado como una clave foránea - Laravel

Tags: laravel, formularios

Buen día, tengo una tabla llamada "categorías", unida mediante llave foránea a otra tabla llamada "productos". Deseo que al intentar eliminar alguna categoría que esté relacionada a productos, me salga algún mensaje que diga que "No se pudo eliminar por que esta categoría esta siendo usada en un producto". Lo que equivaldría al siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado de esta forma:

```
public function eliminar_categoria($id)
{
    if (Categoria::find($id)->delete()) {
         Alert::info('Categoría eliminada correctamente');
        return redirect('/listarCategorias');
    }

    else
    {
        return ("No se pudo eliminar la categoría, por que está asociada a un producto")
    }


}
```

Pero no resulta, por favor si me podrían ayudar o dar ideas de como lograrlo, estaría muy agradecida.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que al ser llave Primaria nunca se va a dejar eliminar a menos que en la BD le pongas en constraint `ONDELETE CASCADE` dicho esto eliminaria la llave primaria y su referencia, pon la estructura de las tablas

Comment: Necesitas un `try...catch`

Answer (score 2):

Le encontré una solución, con un try-catch, aquí dejo el código, aunque seria bueno considerar un borrado lógico, para evitar futuros problemas.

```
public function eliminar_categoria($id)
{
   try {
    Categoria::find($id)->delete();
    Alert::info('Categoría eliminada correctamente');
    return redirect('/listarCategorias');
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
        Alert::error('No se puede eliminar esta categoría, porque está relacionada a un producto', 'Error al eliminar')->autoclose(6000);
        return redirect()->back();
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mmm pues podrías obtener la categoría y checar si tiene productos:

```
$categoria = Categoria::where('id', $id)->with('productos')->first();

if($categoria){
   if($categoria->productos->isNotEmpty()){
      return back()->withErrors('La categoría tiene productos ligados');
   }
   $categoria->delete();
   return back()->with('mensaje', 'La categoría se eliminó exitosamente');
}else{
   return back()->withErrors('La categoría no existe');
}
```

Aunque yo te recomendaría usar `SoftDeletes` para las categorías en tu enfoque de relación categorías - productos para que no se eliminen realmente de la base de datos.

Comment: Gracias y buena respuesta, aun no la he probado, pero solucioné el problema de una manera distinta, igualmente la idea de SoftDeletes, es muy buena, gracias por la contribución.